# UITabBar with additional popup items (a la Tweetbot)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am looking to have many more items in my `UITabBar` than the allowed 5, and I really love how `Tweetbot` allows you to press and hold to switch the last two items to other options.

[image]

Are there any open-source components out there that can replicate this feature? Possibly that are a subclass of `UITabBarController`?

Comment: https://github.com/cjwirth/awesome-ios-ui#tab-bars has a bunch of awesome UI pods. none of the tab bars listed are exactly what you are looking for, but perhaps they have elements/code that could be useful to you or they may inspire something else. cheers